# Set current user in Fabric.UI people picker

Tags: people-picker, typescript, office-ui-fabric-react, office-ui-fabric, webpack

I'm struggling setting the current user to a people picker control in Office.Fabric.UI

```
const people: (IPersonaProps & { key: string | number })[] = [
  {
    key: 1,
    imageInitials: 'PV',
    text: 'Test test',
    secondaryText: 'Designer',
    tertiaryText: 'In a meeting',
    optionalText: 'Available at 4:00pm',
  }
];

public render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <Components.SPPeoplePicker
             selectedItems={people}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Webpack keeps saying

> TS2559: Type '{ selectedItems: string[]; }' has no properties in
>   common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
>   IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly<{ children?:
>   ReactNode; }> & Readonly'.